# Transputer Emulation

Tags: networking, performance, emulation

Given that next year is the 30th anniversary of the Inmos Transputer, I'd like to try to set up a sort of emulation of the distributed architecture using the RPi.  Although I'm only at the planning stage at the moment.

I know of a couple of RPi clusters using either [Beowulf](http://www.zdnet.com/build-your-own-supercomputer-out-of-raspberry-pi-boards-7000015831/) or [Python](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/mediacentre/features/raspberry_pi_supercomputer.shtml), so it should be possible.

How should I set up the communications to the adjacent processors?  Is something like MPI over Ethernet sensible in this configuration?  Should I set my sights on something simpler?

Answer (score 3):

I'm very happy of this idea: I worked on Transputer 30 years ago.

I think that a raspberry can emulate a transputer core easy and that a single raspberry can emulate more than one core.

To extend the emulation it's possible to use MPI to create a computing cluster, but in this project on google sites a different protocol is used:

https://sites.google.com/site/transputeremulator/

Comment: Welcome to [raspberrypi.se]! It would be great if you could provide some information regarding the solution *within* the answer itself. At the moment, the *link* contains the only information that provides a solution to the question, and if ever the linked website/content were to go down, this answer would not be very helpful. Thanks!